# Scrolling through PivotItem with an ad outside the Pivot

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer

I want to place an ad on top of the page with the application name and pivot below it. I want to make the content in the PivotItems scrollable. Therefore, I'm placing a scrollviewer just outside the pivotitem block. I've tried enclosing the AdControl and the Pivot in a grid first and then a StackPanel but in each case, I was unable to scroll through the contents of the PivotItem. The switching between the PivotItems worked perfectly. Where can I place the ScrollViewer to get this desired effect? Also, is there any other place in my layout where this 320X50 ad unit will look better instead of putting it in the top? I also have a CommandBar at the bottom of the page.

```
<StackPanel>
  <UI:AdControl 
  AutoRefreshIntervalInSeconds="60" 
  ApplicationId="be1500d6-9ca7-4a0b-a479-0db279d71e14" 
  AdUnitId="11191335" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
  IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True" 
  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
  Width="320"
  Height="50" IsAutoCollapseEnabled="True"
  />

    <Pivot  x:Uid="Pivot" Title="XYZ" x:Name="pivot" CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True" SelectionChanged="pivot_SelectionChanged">
    <!--Pivot item one-->

    <PivotItem
        x:Uid="PivotItem1"
        Margin="19,14.5,0,0"
        Header="calculate">
        <ScrollViewer>
           <!--<Content>-->
        </ScrollViewer>
    </PivotItem>

   <PivotItem
        x:Uid="PivotItem2"
        Margin="19,14.5,0,0"
        Header="saved">
        <ScrollViewer>
           <!--<Content>-->
        </ScrollViewer>                                   
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: We can help you better if you post your code.